# MLE question given bionomial

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this question.

Among $N$ $i.i.d.$ observations on a $Binomial(2,p)$ random variable, $N_0$ takes on the value 0, $N_1$ takes on the value 1 and $N_2$ take on the value 2. What is the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) of $p$?

**a)** $\widetilde p = (N_1 + N_2)/N$

**b)** $\widetilde p = (2N_1 + N_2)/2N$

**c)** $\widetilde p = (2N_1 + N_2)/N$

**d)** $\widetilde p = (N_1 + 2N_2)/2N$

**e)** $\widetilde p = (N_1 + 2N_2)/N$

I've tried to complete the question but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thank you appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you intend (a) not to show us what you tried? (b) not to tell us what you know about the MLE for $p$? (c) for the last two choices to be the same?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I've corrected the question. I'm just confused how to go about this question. Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

With $X_i \sim \mathsf{Binom}(2, p)$ and $N$ independent observations
$X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$, the MLE of $p$ is $\hat p = \frac{S}{2N},$ where
$S \sim \mathsf{Binom}(2N, p)$ is the number of Successes in the $2N$ trials. If I understand your notation correctly, then the number of Successes is $S =N_1 + 2N_2.$